# loc() ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python

```
    from konlpy.tag import Kkma
    from konlpy.tag import Komoran

    kkma = Kkma()
    komoran = Komoran()
    df['keyword'] = ''
    for idx_line in range(len(df)):
        nouns_list = komoran.nouns(df['title_c'].loc[idx_line])
        nouns_list_c = [nouns for nouns in nouns_list if len(nouns) > 1] 
        if not nouns_list_c :
            continue
        df.loc[[idx_line], 'keyword'] = set(nouns_list_c)
    df = df[df['media'] != '코리아헤럴드']  `your text`
    df = df[df['media'] != '주간경향']    
    df
```

[Result]

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable in ' df.loc[[idx_line], 'keyword'] = set(nouns_list_c)' line
```

Is there any way to insert multiple words into the "keyword" column?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stackoverflow!

The problem here is that pandas, if given a a list, a set, etc, will try to splits its values into different columns.

A workaround can be to insert a string instead of a list (or set) of string, by adding for instance strings separated by a comma:

```
df.loc[[idx_line], 'keyword'] = ', '.join(list(set(nouns_list_c)))
```